# InvokeProcess in TFS2010 build doesn't bubble up errors when I run sqlcmd

Tags: xaml

I am using InvokeProcess task to run SqlCmd in order to execute a sql script against the database. However, if there are errors encountered in the sql script, no errors are raised and the build status is not set to false, as per XAML. What could be happening? 
Here is the code snippet:

```
<mtbwa:InvokeProcess Arguments="[&quot;-b -S server1\dev -U sa -P password -i &quot;&quot;&quot; + SourcesDirectory + &quot;\DatabaseScripts\conversion.sql&quot;&quot;&quot;]" DisplayName="Run Conversion SQL" FileName="c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\sqlcmd.exe" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="464,384" Result="[ExitCode]" WorkingDirectory="[SourcesDirectory]">
<mtbwa:InvokeProcess.ErrorDataReceived>
    <ActivityAction x:TypeArguments="x:String">
        <ActivityAction.Argument>
        <DelegateInArgument x:TypeArguments="x:String" Name="errOutput" />
        </ActivityAction.Argument>
        <Sequence sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="222,208">
            <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
            <scg:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
            <x:Boolean x:Key="IsExpanded">True</x:Boolean>
            </scg:Dictionary>
            </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
            <mtbwa:WriteBuildError DisplayName="VSDBCMD Error" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="200,22" Message="[errOutput]" />
            <mtbwa:SetBuildProperties DisplayName="Set build to failed" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="200,22" PropertiesToSet="Status" Status="[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.BuildStatus.Failed]" />
        </Sequence>
    </ActivityAction>
</mtbwa:InvokeProcess.ErrorDataReceived>
<mtbwa:InvokeProcess.OutputDataReceived>
    <ActivityAction x:TypeArguments="x:String">
        <ActivityAction.Argument>
        <DelegateInArgument x:TypeArguments="x:String" Name="stdOutput" />
        </ActivityAction.Argument>
        <mtbwa:WriteBuildMessage sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="222,22" Message="[stdOutput]" mva:VisualBasic.Settings="Assembly references and imported namespaces serialized as XML namespaces" />
    </ActivityAction>
</mtbwa:InvokeProcess.OutputDataReceived>
<sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
    <scg:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
        <x:Boolean x:Key="IsPinned">False</x:Boolean>
        <x:Boolean x:Key="IsExpanded">True</x:Boolean>
    </scg:Dictionary>
</sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
```

Comment: if you run the same calls with a cmd script, are there non 0 return codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that sqlcmd does not return error codes. I decided to parse the command output looking for failure string and throw an exception if one was found. Here is the snippet:

```
<mtbwa:InvokeProcess Arguments="[&quot;-b -S myServer\dev -U sa -P password -i &quot;&quot;&quot; + SourcesDirectory + &quot;\DatabaseScripts\conversion.sql&quot;&quot;&quot;]" DisplayName="Run Conversion SQL" FileName="c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\sqlcmd.exe" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="464,599" Result="[ExitCode]" WorkingDirectory="[SourcesDirectory]">
<mtbwa:InvokeProcess.ErrorDataReceived>
    <ActivityAction x:TypeArguments="x:String">
    <ActivityAction.Argument>
    <DelegateInArgument x:TypeArguments="x:String" Name="errOutput" />
    </ActivityAction.Argument>
    <Sequence sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="222,208">
    <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
    <scg:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
    <x:Boolean x:Key="IsExpanded">True</x:Boolean>
    </scg:Dictionary>
    </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
    <mtbwa:WriteBuildError DisplayName="VSDBCMD Error" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="200,22" Message="[errOutput]" />
    <mtbwa:SetBuildProperties DisplayName="Set build to failed" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="200,22" PropertiesToSet="Status" Status="[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.BuildStatus.Failed]" />
    </Sequence>
    </ActivityAction>
</mtbwa:InvokeProcess.ErrorDataReceived>
<mtbwa:InvokeProcess.OutputDataReceived>
    <ActivityAction x:TypeArguments="x:String">
        <ActivityAction.Argument>
        <DelegateInArgument x:TypeArguments="x:String" Name="stdOutput" />
        </ActivityAction.Argument>
        <Sequence sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="222,237">
        <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
        <scg:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
        <x:Boolean x:Key="IsExpanded">True</x:Boolean>
        </scg:Dictionary>
        </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
        <mtbwa:WriteBuildMessage sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="200,22" Importance="[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.BuildMessageImportance.High]" Message="[stdOutput]" mva:VisualBasic.Settings="Assembly references and imported namespaces serialized as XML namespaces" />
        <If Condition="[stdOutput.Contains(&quot;The statement has been terminated.&quot;)]" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="200,51">
        <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
        <scg:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
        <x:Boolean x:Key="IsExpanded">False</x:Boolean>
        <x:Boolean x:Key="IsPinned">False</x:Boolean>
        </scg:Dictionary>
        </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
        <If.Then>
        <Sequence sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="281,208">
        <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
        <scg:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
        <x:Boolean x:Key="IsExpanded">True</x:Boolean>
        </scg:Dictionary>
        </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
        <mtbwa:SetBuildProperties DisplayName="Set build to failed" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="200,22" PropertiesToSet="Status" Status="[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.BuildStatus.Failed]" />
        <Throw Exception="[New Exception(&quot;Conversion.sql failed&quot;)]" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="200,22" />
        </Sequence>
        </If.Then>
        </If>
        </Sequence>
    </ActivityAction>
</mtbwa:InvokeProcess.OutputDataReceived>
<sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
    <scg:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
    <x:Boolean x:Key="IsPinned">False</x:Boolean>
    <x:Boolean x:Key="IsExpanded">True</x:Boolean>
    </scg:Dictionary>
</sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
```